# Embed external .exe into .jar file in a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, resources, nexus

I have a Maven project converted from a Java project.

My project structure only contains one folder for sources (/src) and doesn't look like a standard Maven project which creates /src/main/java and /src/test/java folders.
I'm trying to add a resource to this project. The resource will be pulled from Nexus and it is a zip archive that contains an .exe file. I've added the following into pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupid>group.id</groupid>
<artifactid>artifactid</artifactid>
<version>1.0</version>
<type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

The resource (zip file) is downloaded in .m2/repository/.../.../. I would need a way to access the resource (unzip it and run the .exe file) and also, I would like this resource to be embedded in the .jar file that I'll export.

Basically, I want to embbed an external .exe file into a .jar file and be able to execute it. The .exe file is stored in an acrhive on Nexus.

Is there any way to achive this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To grab and unzip an artifact, simply use the mvn dependency:unpack goal (No need for dependency here, but it might be implied)

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html

To execute an executable, use the mvn exec:exec goal

http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html

I don't understand your final requirements, but I hope the above helps.